# Know all path's to a folder inside folder using shell script or bat script

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, git-bash

I have a Directory named `A` on Desktop.

It has the following hierarchy:

```
A -> B -> C -> D

A -> Q -> W -> X -> D

A -> S -> D -> F
```

All the above are Directory names. I want to know if a directory named `D` is there inside directory `A`. After ensuring the existence of `D`, I want to know the full path(s) from directory `A` to `D`.

Someone please help me in this regard.

Comment: If it's unix based os, you can use find command.

Comment: No, I am on windows, running the command in git shell. It's not identifying find command.

Comment: @BarathVutukuri, why won't you use **`Cygwin`**?

Comment: If you are tagging a question for `bash`, we would generally assume that the standard tools available along with `bash` are present.

Comment: @anishsane removed the bash tag. Sorry for Confusion*.

Comment: Not inconvenience, it creates confusion. You are given answers, which are possibly not going to work on your setup...

Comment: @BarathVutukuri: Do you mean **this**, when you say 'git-shell'?    https://git-scm.com/docs/git-shell    . In this case, I don't see how it relates to bash. What exactly is your execution environment?

Comment: @user1934428 it is git bash

Comment: I just read about git bash (https://msysgit.github.io/). It really seems to be "just bash", without any other tools, and it means that you really don't have "find" and "dirname" and the like available. If this is the case, you have two choices: You are writing a bash program to do what you want (which is possible, because bash is a programming language), or - and this is what I would recommend - drop git-bash and install Cygwin with bash, zsh and the like. You can also use the Cygwin version of git. This is how I am doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Using find inside A:
Unix

```
find . -name "D" -type d
```

Windows

```
dir A /AD /S
```

Comment: I am on windows machine find command is not working. I am using these commands in git shell.

Comment: I want to print the full path to that folder if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about git-bash.

Crazy as it seems, native batch does not have a direct way to list all locations of a specific folder name. Unless the DIR command includes a wild card, then DIR will look for files or folders within the specified folder, rather than listing the folder name itself.

The solution is to pipe the result to FINDSTR

```
dir /s /b /ad A | findstr /irc:"[\\]D$"
```

Performance might be optimized a wee bit if the target folder name is added to the DIR command, with a wildcard appended:

```
dir /s /b /ad A\D? | findstr /irc:"[\\]D$"
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this is what you mean, but ...

.... Setup ....

```
user@machine ~:$ mkdir tmp
user@machine ~:$ cd tmp
user@machine ~/tmp:$ mkdir -p A/B/C/D
user@machine ~/tmp:$ mkdir -p A/Q/W/X/D
user@machine ~/tmp:$ mkdir -p A/S/D/F
```

... find command ....

```
user@machine ~/tmp:$ find ./ -type d -name 'D'
./A/B/C/D
./A/S/D
./A/Q/W/X/D
user@machine ~/tmp:$
```

Comment: The command you gave prints all the hierarchy. If such folder exists, I want it to print only the hierarchy to that folder.

Comment: Why -1? Is `find A -type d -name 'D'` what you want?

Comment: @BarathVutukuri: This is not correct. The command which is proposed here, only prints the pathes leading to directory D. Of course there are several pathes, because there are several directories of this name.

Comment: @user1934428 I want the command to print only the paths leading to folder D

Comment: Bit hacky but ... **find ./ -type d -name 'D'|sed 's/D$//'**

Comment: But these ARE the pathes leading to folders D: './A/B/C/D' is the path to one D, './A/S/D' is the path to another D, and so on. If you want to exclude the name "D" from the path, use 'dirname'.